# How do you specify a class with $(this)

Tags: jquery

Change an entry in one of the input fields, then. click enter key on your computer. The desired result is to have only the corresponding span tag(class="note") within the p tag to show input results; not all span tags as demonstrated in this example. How do you define $(".note") as "this class". I have tried everything.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p > .test").change(function(){
    $(".note").html($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><input type="text" class="test" value="Mickey Mouse"><span class="note"></span></p>
<p><input type="text" class="test" value="Mickey Mouse"><span class="note"></span></p>
<p><input type="text" class="test" value="Mickey Mouse"><span class="note"></span></p>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/skj77nt0/5/

Comment: There is a reason for the jsFiddle link-only restriction. Include your code in the question, how hard can that be? Even worse, your actual question  is contained in the fiddle... wth?

Comment: You should post your code here to ensure it is preserved for future generations.

Comment: Please post your code for the question to be self-sufficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('.note')` will collect all elements of that class in the page.

Within a jQuery event handler, `this` is the element in the matching selector that the event occurred on. You can then use traverses from your element, one simple one would be `siblings()`

```
$("p > .test").change(function(){
  $(this).siblings(".note").html($(this).val());
});
```

Some alternative traverses

```
$(this).next()
$(this).parent().find('.note')
$(this).closest('p').find('.note')
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ak9zj7w2/)**</kbd>

Comment: Wow!  Thank you charlietfl! I knew I was missing something i.e. siblings never showed up in my search for an answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You want the [jQuery `.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p > .test").change(function(){
    $(this).next(".note").html($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's many [traversal methods](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) to target the right node. A possible solution would be to get the next element sibling of `this`:

```
$(this).next().html(...);
```

Another one would be to get the `.note` child of `this`' parent:

```
$(this).parent().children('.note').html(...);
```